# Mongo C#Driver:Deserialize BsonArray

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a document in mongodb that is structured similar to this:

```
{
    "_id":xxxxx,
    "business":[{
            "subBusiness":[{
                "subBusinessName":"Abusiness",
                "a":"aaaa"
            },{
                "subBusinessName":"Bbusiness",
                "b":"bbbbb",
                "c":"ccccc"
                }]
        }]
}
```

how to make a mapping class to serialize this document?

I also have a class defined to represent dimensions (the sub document from above)

```
class STObject{
    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId id{get;set;}
    [BsonElement("business")]
    public List<Business> BusinessList{get;set;}
}
class Business  {   
    [BsonElement("subBusiness")]
    public List<SubBusiness> SubBuiness { get; set; }
}
[BsonDiscriminator(RootClass = true)]
[BsonKnownTypes(typeof(CSSubBusiness),typeof(ApproSubBusiness))]
public class SubBusiness {
    [BsonElement("subBusinessName")]
    public string SubBusinessName{get;set;}
}
public class AsubBusiness:SubBusiness{
    [BsonElement("a")]
    public string A{get;set;}   
}
public class BsubBusiness:SubBusiness{
    [BsonElement("b")]
    public string B{get;set;}
    [BsonElement("c")]
    public string C{get;set;}
}
```

how to query  element "b" in class  STObject?

Answer (score 2):

In order to [deserialize class hierarchy](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/serialize-documents-with-the-csharp-driver/#polymorphic-classes-and-discriminators), document should contain type discriminator field, which tells which type of subclass should be instantiated. By default this field has name `_t`. But if you already have documents with schema as above and can't change it, then you should override discriminator convention which is used by Mongo.

Looks like you can use `subBusinessName` field as type discriminator for sub business types. In order to do that, you should remove this field from base type:

```
[BsonDiscriminator(RootClass = true)]
[BsonKnownTypes(typeof(AsubBusiness), typeof(BsubBusiness))] // btw check types
public class SubBusiness
{        
}
```

And you should provide discriminator values for subtypes:

```
[BsonDiscriminator("Abusiness")] // provide discriminator value here
public class AsubBusiness : SubBusiness
{
    [BsonElement("a")]
    public string A { get; set; }
}

[BsonDiscriminator("Bbusiness")]
public class BsubBusiness : SubBusiness
{
    [BsonElement("b")]
    public string B { get; set; }
    [BsonElement("c")]
    public string C { get; set; }
}
```

And final step - create custom convention to make mongo look on this discriminator field for instantiating correct sub class type:

```
public class SubBusinessDiscriminatorConvention : IDiscriminatorConvention
{
    public string ElementName
    {
        get { return "subBusinessName"; }
    }

    public Type GetActualType(BsonReader bsonReader, Type nominalType)
    {
        var bookmark = bsonReader.GetBookmark();
        bsonReader.ReadStartDocument();
        var actualType = nominalType;
        if (bsonReader.FindElement(ElementName))
        {
            var discriminator = (BsonValue)BsonValueSerializer.Instance.Deserialize(bsonReader, typeof(BsonValue), null);
            actualType = BsonSerializer.LookupActualType(nominalType, discriminator);
        }
        bsonReader.ReturnToBookmark(bookmark);
        return actualType;
    }

    public BsonValue GetDiscriminator(Type nominalType, Type actualType)
    {
        var classMap = BsonClassMap.LookupClassMap(actualType);
        return classMap.Discriminator;
    }
}
```

Now set this convention for your base type serialization:

```
BsonSerializer.RegisterDiscriminatorConvention(typeof(SubBusiness), 
    new SubBusinessDiscriminatorConvention());
```

And you can serialize and deserialize documents in your exact format.

UPDATE: Querying:

```
var collection = test.GetCollection<STObject>("collectionName");
var sto = collection.FindOne(Query.EQ("_id", new ObjectId("xxxxx")));
var businessList = sto.BusinessList.FirstOrDefault();
var bsub = businessList.SubBuiness.OfType<BsubBusiness>().FirstOrDefault();
var b = bsub.B; // returns bbbbb
```

Comment: thanks very much，how to query element "b" in class BsubBusiness ?